# redux state doesn't have updated value in InterSectionObserver callback function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit, intersection-observer

I am using `IntersectionObserver` api for implementing infinite scroll. When callback is called ,then inside the `callback`,redux state does not have updated value.The functions are:

```js
//function for defining InfiniteScroll
const InfiniteScroll = (parent,target,options,callback,getObject)=>{
    const Infoptions = {
        root: parent,
        rootMargin: '50px',
        threshold: 1.0,
        ...options
      }
      
      let observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, Infoptions);
      observer.observe(target);      
      getObject(observer);
      
}


export default InfiniteScroll;
```

This function is used here:

```js
//calling InfiniteScroll
    const target = useRef();
    const parent = useRef();
    const observer = useRef();
    const state = useSelector((state)=>state);

    useEffect(() => {
        if(!loading){
            
            InfiniteScroll(parent.current, target.current, {}, callbackScroll, function (obs) {
                observer.current = obs;
            })
        }
        return () => {
            observer.current&&observer.current.disconnect();
        }
    }, [loading])

    const callbackScroll = useCallback((data, observer) => {
        
        if (data[0].isIntersecting) {
            if ((state.post.data[postid]?.hasmorecomments) !== false){
                //if there are more comments ,then this function will call api to fetch comments
                FetchPostComments();
                //here (state.post.data[postid]) returns undefined value,
                //which is the initial value(when component has not mounted),
                //but in some_other function ,it returns updated value
                console.log((state.post.data[postid]));
            }
        }
    },[FetchPostComments])
```

```js
const some_other = ()=>{
   //here it logs expected value(an object,not undefined)
   console.log(state.post.data[postid]);
}
```

I want the updated value inside `callbackScroll` function just like the function `some_other`. How may i achieve it?

**Edit-1 : jsx code where target is being used**

```
//parent is the reference to scrollable div   
return (
     <div ref={parent}>
           <Comments/>
           {//here too, state.post.data[postid] has updated value}
           {((state.post.data[postid]?.hasmorecomments) !== false)&&<Loader/>}
            <div ref={target}></div>
     </div>
)
```

Comment: can you add code where you are using target?

Comment: @RahulSharma hi, I have edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was basically with dependency array of `useEffect` and `useCallback`

```js
useEffect(() => {
        if(!loading){
            
            InfiniteScroll(parent.current, target.current, {}, callbackScroll, function (obs) {
                observer.current = obs;
            })
        }
        return () => {
            observer.current&&observer.current.disconnect();
        }
    }, [loading,parent,target,callbackScroll,observer])

const callbackScroll = useCallback((data, observer) => {
        
        if (data[0].isIntersecting) {
            if ((state.post.data[postid]?.hasmorecomments) !== false){
                //if there are more comments ,then this function will call api to fetch comments
                FetchPostComments();
                //here (state.post.data[postid]) returns undefined value,
                //which is the initial value(when component has not mounted),
                //but in some_other function ,it returns updated value
                console.log((state.post.data[postid]));
            }
        }
    },[FetchPostComments,state]) //Include state in dependency array
```

Answer (score 4):

The purpose of using a `useCallback` is to avoid unnecessary function invocation every time when a parent component or self is re-rendered, this is achieved by returning a memorized version of the callback function, that is invoked only when the state or reference value in the dependency array change. The function inside the `useCallback` is executed only once when the component is initially mounted with initial state values.
Hence, it is returning `undefined`. You'd want it to execute again when the state is updated (i.e invoke the function when the state is updated to contain more comments in this case). You can accomplish this by simply including the state in the dependency array of your `useCallback` hook.

```
const callbackScroll = useCallback((data, observer) => {
        
        if (data[0].isIntersecting) {
            if ((state.post.data[postid]?.hasmorecomments) !== false){
                //if there are more comments ,then this function will call api to fetch comments
                FetchPostComments();
                //here (state.post.data[postid]) returns undefined value,
                //which is the initial value(when component has not mounted),
                //but in some_other function ,it returns updated value
                console.log((state.post.data[postid]));
            }
        }
    },[FetchPostComments,state]) //Include state in dependency array
```

Comment: Tried but it is still not working !!!

Comment: worked after i included `parent`,`target`,`callbackScroll` and `observer` in useEffect dependencies

Comment: Ah, that's right. Since the unmounting/mounting also depends on `observer` and other related instances, it is required to include those dependencies as well.